# Converting data from fortran to python

Tags: python, fortran

I'm new to programming and now I'm trying to rewrite the Fortran code in Python script.

In original fortran code, it declares real number as:

```
Begin
c----
      data (A(0,i), i=0,17)   
     &  /
     &    9.526e5, 1.416e6, 1.210e6, 7.734e5, 4.050e5, 1.851e5,
     &    7.944e4, 3.382e4, 1.434e4, 5.821e3, 2.174e3, 7.392e2,
     &    2.349e2, 7.361e1, 2.405e1, 8.423e0, 3.120e0, 1.176e0
     &  /
c----
c---- End
```

Here how can I convert this A_ul(0,i) in python code? And how can i rewrite A(0,i) to calculate :

```
B = (p**2)*(c**3)*A_ul(0,i)
```

Such that p and c are constants

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran-related questions.

Comment: To anyone answering this with Python code or reading the answers, please note that the Fortran `data` statement isn't the same thing as an assignment statement.  Simply writing a Python assignment isn't going to capture all complexity of this Fortran snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Choices

**Option 1: Using Normal Python Lists**

[Python List Comprehension Tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-list-comprehension)

```
A_ul = [9.526e5, 1.416e6, 1.210e6, 7.734e5, 4.050e5, 1.851e5,
        7.944e4, 3.382e4, 1.434e4, 5.821e3, 2.174e3, 7.392e2,
        2.349e2, 7.361e1, 2.405e1, 8.423e0, 3.120e0, 1.176e0]

# some values for p, c (assuming scalars)
p = 2.95
c = 3.41

# generate computation of scalar with array using list comprehension
B = [(p**2)*(c**3)*x for x in A_ul] 

print(B)
```

*Out*

```
[328713655.56773156, 488619080.70954007, 417534666.42552507, 266877116.54008356, 139753338.76226252, 63872451.863937765, 27412358.595738605, 11670266.461579552, 4948303.402100851, 2008652.308481803, 750182.1196769351, 255075.72348904808, 81056.93648211227, 25400.60065750653, 8298.932832672626, 2906.524376282808, 1076.6183134278003, 405.80228736894003]
```

**Option 2: Using Python Numpy Arrays**

Numpy allows easy array and matrix expressions in Python (i.e. an alternative to Matlab)

[Numpy tutorial](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/python-numpy-tutorial)

```
import numpy as np

# A_ul as Numpy array
A_ul = np.array([9.526e5, 1.416e6, 1.210e6, 7.734e5, 4.050e5, 1.851e5,
        7.944e4, 3.382e4, 1.434e4, 5.821e3, 2.174e3, 7.392e2,
        2.349e2, 7.361e1, 2.405e1, 8.423e0, 3.120e0, 1.176e0])
# some values for p, c (assuming scalars)
p = 2.95
c = 3.41

# numpy understands multiplying scalars by arrays
B = (p**2)*(c**3)*A_ul 

print(B)
```

*Out*

```
[3.28713656e+08 4.88619081e+08 4.17534666e+08 2.66877117e+08
 1.39753339e+08 6.38724519e+07 2.74123586e+07 1.16702665e+07
 4.94830340e+06 2.00865231e+06 7.50182120e+05 2.55075723e+05
 8.10569365e+04 2.54006007e+04 8.29893283e+03 2.90652438e+03
 1.07661831e+03 4.05802287e+02]
```